# Directory listing + multi pattern + acces denied

Tags: .net

i have tried many samples on the net to list all files in system directory via (.net 2 window form).

does anyone knows a function which can Directory listing + multi pattern  + hidden system files

I have found the solution at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/xdirectorycopy.aspx

Comment: so to be clear: you want a way to be able to override system security when listing directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't one. You'll have to do recursive calls to `Directory.GetFiles` and `Directory.GetDirectories`. Or possibly `EnumerateDirectories` and `EnumerateFiles`.

See this article for details and sample code: [How to recursively search directories by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974)